# Inequality with invertible symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B, J$ be two real matrices such that $B$ is symmetric invertible and $J = \left( \begin{matrix}0& I\\ -I & L \end{matrix}\right),$ where $L :=\left( \begin{matrix}0& 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$. I'd like to know wether we have an inequality of this type 
$$ \Big|\langle BJBv,w\rangle \Big| \leq C \Big|\langle Jv,w\rangle \Big|, \quad v, w \in \mathbb{R}^4,$$ where $\langle, \rangle $ is the usual scalar product and $C$ is some constant which might depend on $B$.

As a first step, one can start with $\langle BJBv,w\rangle = \langle JBv,B w\rangle.$

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly not, because the LHS can be nonzero when the RHS vanishes. E.g. let $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$ and
$$v=\pmatrix{-1\\ 0\\ 0\\ \phi},\ w=\pmatrix{0\\ 1\\ 1-\phi\\ 0},\ B=\pmatrix{2\\ &1\\ &&1 \\ &&&1}.$$
Then $\langle Jv,w\rangle=0$ but $\langle JBv,Bw\rangle=1-\phi$.

Comment: Thank you for this counter-example. Can we find another example for the special case of $J = \left(\begin{matrix}0& I\\ -I&  L\end{matrix}\right),$ where $L$ is the $2\times 2$ bloc appearing in your example for $J.$ ???

Comment: Sorry! The matrix $L := \left(\begin{matrix}0& 1\\ -1& 0\end{matrix}\right)$ so that we have now $J^2 = - I $

Comment: Sorry again... I am really interested in this special case of $J = \left( \begin{matrix}0& I\\ -I & L \end{matrix}\right),$ where $L :=\left( \begin{matrix}0& 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$. I was confused with the bloc $L$ which satisfies this condition $L^2 = -I$. I edited the main question.